# Using RegionPlot to show when two sums are both negaitve

Tags: plotting

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[k_, \[Alpha]_, \[Theta]_] := 
 Sum[(Cos[m \[Theta]] (Sin[m k])^2)/m^(1 + \[Alpha]), {m, 1, Infinity}]
h[k_, \[Alpha]_, \[Theta]_] := 
 Sum[(Cos[m \[Theta]] (Sin[m k])^2)/m^(1 + \[Alpha]), {m, 1, 2}]
```

I have two sums which I want to know when are both negative given the fixed parameters $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and $\kappa \in [-\pi,\pi]$ with $\theta\in[-\pi,\pi]$ varying.
In particular, for what range of theta are both sums negative. To see this, I tried using the following command:

```
RegionPlot[And[h[\[Pi]/2,1,\[Theta]]<0, f[\[Pi]/2,1,\[Theta]]<0], {\[Theta],-2\[Pi],2\[Pi]}]
```

but this yielded the error

> RegionPlot::argrx: RegionPlot called with 2 arguments; 3 arguments are
> expected.

Further, I want exact bounds on theta instead of visually observing when both sums are negative via the RegionPlot approach. How can I obtain that? Even better if both $\kappa$ AND $\theta$ can vary with fixed $\alpha$.

Comment: `RegionPlot` needs a range for both axes. Example from documentation: `RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `α=1`
(`f` was giving errors, but changing `Infinity` to 100 seems to help)

```
f[k_, α_, θ_] := 
 Sum[(Cos[m θ] (Sin[m k])^2)/m^(1 + α), {m, 1, 100}]
h[k_, α_, θ_] := 
 Sum[(Cos[m θ] (Sin[m k])^2)/m^(1 + α), {m, 1, 2}]

RegionPlot[
 And[h[k, 1, θ] < 0, f[k, 1, θ] < 0], 
{θ, -π, π}, {k, -π, π}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Edited to add something about finding the boundaries:

It's quite slow - maybe someone else can post a better solution. Changing the upper limit of the sum in `f` to 50 to make it faster:

In the `θ` dimension

```
fhboundary[k_] := 
 Reduce[{f[k, 1, θ] < 0, 
   h[k, 1, θ] < 0, -π <= θ <= π}, θ, Reals]
```

Then, for example, at `k=1`

```
fhboundary[1] // N

 (* -3.14159 <= θ < -1.36318 || 1.36318 < θ <= 3.14159 *)
```

And in the `k` dimension

```
fhboundary2[θ_] := 
 Reduce[{And[f[k, 1, θ] < 0, h[k, 1, θ] < 0], -π <= 
    k <= π}, k, Reals]

fhboundary2[6/5] // N

 (* -3.14159 < k < -2.3476 || -0.793995 < k < 0. || 0. < k < 0.793995 || 
 2.3476 < k < 3.14159 *)
```

Comment: Do you also know how to the exact bounds on theta and k for which these regions hold?

Comment: @KZ-Spectra, see edits to answer